# Turn off "Unfortunately [app] has stopped" popup

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, lg, magisk, popup

I'm wondering if it's possible to disable this popup. I've an old phone that I use rarely where I uninstalled some critical apps, that I don't use. Phone works flawlessly apart from constant popups. Maybe there is a Magisk module or something. Thanks